# How do I use a GtkComboBox with objects, as opposed to strings?

Tags: mono, gtk

The usual use for a combo box is to let it display options to the user, and then you get an OBJECT out of it. In Win32, you do it by using the CB_SETITEMDATA and CB_GETITEMDATA messages, casting between int and object pointers. In XAML, you set up a data template and the item in the list IS the object.

What is the Correct way to get this effect with a GtkComboBox?

Answer (score 0):

GtkComboBox normally uses a GtkListStore as the underlaying model.
You need to create one with an extra column for the object you want to store and as you insert new items in the combo's model you also need to provide the object you want to associate with that row/item.